# How to understand 'a sound principle'

Tags: meaning

*A sound principle* seems to be commonly used. But sound has several meanings, it can either refer to solid and strong or free from error.

Is *a sound principle* like a solid principle or a wise principle (showing good judgment)?

Comment: The two meanings are etymologically related. They all extend from the sense of ["free from defect or injury."](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sound)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of "sound" refers to being *solid* or *stable* particularly on structures or pieces of wood. That brings along *reliable* and then *orthodox* or correct.

A later definition in Merriam Webster includes "free from error, fallacy, or misapprehension". This would agree with your idea of being free from error.

A principle is a general structure or framework of ideas. It can rarely be said to be entirely correct or free from error since it may be used to cover many areas of interest. Similarly a sound structure cannot be said to be entirely free from error (my opinion) since it may be vast and an error can be small.

Solid and wise are both good descriptions of a sound principle. That is, it should be the best option available even if not always perfect.